# I'm getting an error saying I'm inserting a duplicate entry when there isn't one

Tags: database

I have a form for users to update labels for cameras that my Drupal 7 module is displaying.  When the user submits the form, first I check to see if the submitted value already exists int he DB:

```
$query = db_select('floormap_cameras', 't')
      ->fields('t')
      ->condition('camera_name', $_POST['camera_update'][1], '=')
      ->execute()->fetchAll();
var_dump($query);
```

Then, if the value doesn't return any rows, I update the 'camera_name' field for the matching address:

```
if (empty($query[0]->camera_name)) {
   try {
     $update = db_update('floormap_cameras')
        ->fields(array(
          'camera_name' => $_POST['camera_update'][1],
        ))
        ->condition('address', $_POST['camera_update'][0], '=')
        ->execute();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
    }
```

This is where the trouble comes in....no matter what I put in for the new label, I get an error saying:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'Shannon6' for key 'camera_name'

I get this even though nothing I attempt to enter is already in the table.  The update shouldn't even run if the value is being used, I'm only running it if the first query returns nothing matching the label.

Here is the contents of the table, as you can see the value from the error posted is not in the table:

mysql> SELECT * FROM tlsconnectapp.floormap_cameras;

+------------+-------------+

| address    | camera_name |

+------------+-------------+

| monitor=30 | Counter C   |

| monitor=31 | Counter D   |

| monitor=33 | Counter E   |

| monitor=34 | Counter F   |

| monitor=35 | Counter G   |

| monitor=36 | Counter H   |

| monitor=29 | Counter V   |

| monitor=28 | monitor_28  |

| monitor=29 | monitor_29  |

| monitor=30 | monitor_30  |

| monitor=31 | monitor_31  |

| monitor=32 | monitor_32  |

| monitor=33 | monitor_33  |

| monitor=34 | monitor_34  |

| monitor=35 | monitor_35  |

| monitor=36 | monitor_36  |

| monitor=28 | TestCam     |

| monitor=32 | Waiting     |

+------------+-------------+

18 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error?